# Verify which columns have changed in a datatable or datarow

Tags: c#

I was asked to update a business rule to allow a specific column to be added. Because our datalayer uses only DataSets as an interface to the database that is what we work with in the business layer.

Here I have created a couple of `DataTable` and `DataRow` extensions to use for this businessrule and I would like your opinion on things I might have missed.
This is the method I use to search for changes:

```
private static bool hasColumnChanged(StringComparison stringComparison, bool ignoreWhitespace, DataRow row, DataColumn col)
{
    bool isEqual = true;
    if (row[col, DataRowVersion.Original] != DBNull.Value && row[col, DataRowVersion.Current] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        if (ignoreWhitespace)
            isEqual = row[col, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString().Trim().Equals(row[col, DataRowVersion.Current].ToString().Trim(), stringComparison);
        else
            isEqual = row[col, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString().Equals(row[col, DataRowVersion.Current].ToString(), stringComparison);
    }
    else
        isEqual = row[col, DataRowVersion.Original].Equals(row[col, DataRowVersion.Current]);

    return !isEqual;
}
```

And these are simply the extensions using the code:

```
public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataTable table) 
{
    return table.GetChangedColumns(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, false);
}
public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataTable table, bool ignoreWhitespace)
{
    return table.GetChangedColumns(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, ignoreWhitespace);
}
public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataTable table, StringComparison stringComparison, bool ignoreWhitespace)
{
    if (table == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("table");

    List<DataColumn> columnsChanged = new List<DataColumn>();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.GetChanges().Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            if (!columnsChanged.Contains(col) && hasColumnChanged(stringComparison, ignoreWhitespace, row, col))
                columnsChanged.Add(col);
        }
    }
    return columnsChanged;
}

public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataRow row)
{
    return row.GetChangedColumns(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, false);
}
public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataRow row, bool ignoreWhitespace)
{
    return row.GetChangedColumns(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, ignoreWhitespace);
}
public static List<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataRow row, StringComparison stringComparison, bool ignoreWhitespace)
{
    if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("row");

    List<DataColumn> columnsChanged = new List<DataColumn>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        if (!columnsChanged.Contains(col) && hasColumnChanged(stringComparison, ignoreWhitespace, row, col))
            columnsChanged.Add(col);
    }
    return columnsChanged;
}
```

To test the above code I use this simple unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DataTableAndDataRowGetChangedColumns()
{
    DataSet ds = GetDummyDataSet();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3] = DateTime.Now;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][2].ToString() + " ";
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] = DBNull.Value;
    List<DataColumn> changesForRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].GetChangedColumns(true);
    List<DataColumn> changesForTable = ds.Tables[0].GetChangedColumns(true);

    // For now we just verify if the amount of changes is the same (ez way out)
    Assert.IsTrue(changesForRow.Count.Equals(changesForTable.Count));
}
```

In the business rule I have implemented this piece of code which verifies if there are other datacolumns that have changed:

```
List<DataColumn> columnsChanged = dsChanges.Tables[0].GetChangedColumns(true);
if(columnsChanged.Any(c=>!c.ColumnName.Equals("DateUntill", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    throw new BusinessException("This premium can not be changed, only DateUntill can still change");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `hasColumnChanged` method. Inside first `if` you have two almost same lines. Duplicated code should be extracted:

   ```
   if (row[col, DataRowVersion.Original] != DBNull.Value && row[col, DataRowVersion.Current] != DBNull.Value)  
   {  
       string originalVersionToCompare = row[col, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
       string currentVersionToCompare = row[col, DataRowVersion.Current].ToString();
       if (ignoreWhitespace)
       {
           originalVersionToCompare = originalVersionToCompare.Trim();
           currentVersionToCompare = currentVersionToCompare.Trim();
       }
       isEqual = originalVersionToCompare.Equals(currentVersionToCompare, stringComparison);
   }
   ```
2. If you have .Net 4.0 then 6 `GetChangedColumns` methods I would refactor into 2 with optional parameters.
3. `foreach` inside `GetChangedColumns` for `DataRow` looks like a copypaste. I cannot imagine a situation when `columnsChanged.Contains(col)` will be true in this method.
4. `hasColumnChanged` seems to be named incorrectly. It should be `hasCellChanged` since it checks for intersection of row and column. Maybe also `PascalCase`?
5. LINQify it!

   Original:

   ```
   List<DataColumn> columnsChanged = new List<DataColumn>();
   foreach (DataRow row in table.GetChanges().Rows)
   {
       foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
       {
           if (!columnsChanged.Contains(col) && hasColumnChanged(stringComparison, ignoreWhitespace, row, col))
               columnsChanged.Add(col);
       }
   }
   return columnsChanged;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   return table.GetChanges().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
       .SelectMany(dr => table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>(), (row, column) => new {row, column})
       .Where(c => hasColumnChanged(stringComparison, ignoreWhitespace, c.row, c.column))
       .Select(c => c.column)
       .Distinct()
       .ToList();
   ```
6. `DateUntill` - double `l`?
7. Why do you compare items by casting them to string? Why don't you compare them as objects?

Comment: Wauw this is some really good feedback. I thought my initial code was a very good start so I wouldn't get much suggested changes. But you've made it much clearer and taught me a thing or two :-) I'm using camelCasing on the private methods as this is our inhouse coding convention. Thanks!

Comment: 7. I compare them by string so I'm able to specify a StringComparison type, else I have to check if the column datatype is of string first. In the end I don't see the problem in doing this as the result of "1"=="1" equals 1==1. And this is true for all datatypes since the conversion from datatype to string is the same for both.

Comment: @Peter, I would better add `string` type check other than remembering how different objects are converted to string. For example usually `DateTime.ToString()` doesn't print milliseconds so your comparison will not catch changes in milliseconds. That's just an example, probably it won't be an often situation.

Comment: On `5.`: The original is clearer, so I would prefer it. Maintainability trumps most other values.

Comment: Actually, optional arguments is not a feature of .net 4.0, but of the c# 4.0 compiler (which is included in VS2010 and **can be used also with .net 3.5 for example**).

Comment: Though I have a question, shouldn't you simply use: !Equals(row[col, DataRowVersion.Original], row[col, DataRowVersion.Current])?